# SAS count of variables

Tags: count, sas

%let var= A B C D E; when I do the do loop %do i=1 %to 5; instead of hard code 5, I want to use count(A B C D E) or something similar. Because in the future, var may change to A B C D, then 5 will become 4. Need your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTW() with a fully worked example of exactly what you're attempting in the [SAS Macro Appendix](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=mcrolref&docsetTarget=n02xowj8yuqfo4n0zzi98shu8qup.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en):

```
%macro iterm(lst);
 %let finish=%sysfunc(countw(&lst));
  %do i = 1 %to &finish;
   %put %scan(&lst,&i);
  %end;
%mend iterm;

%iterm(a c e)
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need. Thank you.